# How to stop Nginx from adding port to external urls when it does reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, nginx, cdn, cloudinary

I am facing an issue with **Nginx** in serving **Cloudinary** urls.

I have set up a reverse proxy which basically servers my localhost application for public and forces https as well.

I am using Cloudinary as my image service.

The issue is for some reason Nginx adds **:80** to the host part of my Cloudinary urls and it causes a 404 error.

As an example all of my urls become **https://res.cloudinary.com:80/...**

Here is my reverse proxy config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name test.example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen   443;
    server_name test.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.example.com/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your `nginx` config, it will proxy all the requests under `/` to `http://localhost:8080`. I'm unable to see from the above config snippet that it would proxied to https://res.cloudinary.com:80/.

If I have to guess, it's the application/service that running on your localhost on port 8080 that responsible to that. Have you check if that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in my React JS code and was not related to Nginx.